# Converting int/bool/etc. to T if the type matches

Tags: c#, methods, types

I have this function:

```cs
private T Load<T> (string name)
{
    string value;

    // ...

    T convertedValue;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        convertedValue = int.Parse(value);

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
        convertedValue = float.Parse(value);

    // etc.

    return(convertedValue);
}
```

The problem is that I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T'` and `Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'T'` error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you shouldn't really use generics like that. separate methods would be way better

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought there may be an easier way

Comment: This is an XY problem. You are asking us to fix something that what you think is the solution to your problem. However, it is not a good solution. If you give us the underlying problem you are trying to solve, we can help you find a good solution.

Comment: Using specialization *within* a generic method is a code-smell: it indicates that it probably shouldn't be generic in the first place. Instead you probably need different functions

Answer (score 0):

how to use it in my own projects

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static bool TryTypeNullable(Type value, out Type outvalue)
        {
            var t = (value.IsGenericType && value.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
            outvalue = (t ? value.GenericTypeArguments[0] : value); return t;
        }
        public static object ChangeType(object value, Type type)
        {
            var c = TryTypeNullable(type, out _);
            return (c && value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, c ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) : type);
        }
        public static TKey ValueOrNull<TKey>(this string value)
        {
            value = (value ?? "").Trim();
            if (value == "") { return default; }
            else
            {
                var tp = typeof(TKey);
                var p = TryTypeNullable(tp, out Type ufc);
                var typs = Type.GetTypeCode(ufc);
                if (typs == TypeCode.Empty || typs == TypeCode.DBNull) { return default; }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Object)
                {
                    if (ufc.Name == nameof(Guid))
                    {
                        if (Guid.TryParse(value, out Guid bt) && bt != Guid.Empty) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                        else { return default; }
                    }
                    else { throw new Exception("ex..."); }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Boolean)
                {
                    if (Boolean.TryParse(value, out bool bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Char)
                {
                    if (Char.TryParse(value, out char bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.SByte)
                {
                    if (SByte.TryParse(value, out sbyte bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Byte)
                {
                    if (Byte.TryParse(value, out byte bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Int16)
                {
                    if (Int16.TryParse(value, out short bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.UInt16)
                {
                    if (UInt16.TryParse(value, out ushort bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Int32)
                {
                    if (Int32.TryParse(value, out int bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.UInt32)
                {
                    if (UInt32.TryParse(value, out uint bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Int64)
                {
                    if (Int64.TryParse(value, out long bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.UInt64)
                {
                    if (UInt64.TryParse(value, out ulong bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Single)
                {
                    if (Single.TryParse(value.Replace(".", ",").ToString(), out float bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Double)
                {
                    if (Double.TryParse(value.Replace(".", ",").ToString(), out double bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.Decimal)
                {
                    if (Decimal.TryParse(value.Replace(".", ",").ToString(), out decimal bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.DateTime)
                {
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime bt)) { return (TKey)ChangeType(bt, tp); }
                    else { return default; }
                }
                else if (typs == TypeCode.String) { return (TKey)ChangeType(value, tp); }
                else { throw new NotImplementedException("ex..."); }
            }
        }
    }
```

examples

```
var f = "Lorem ipsum".ValueOrNull<Guid?>() // result -> null
var f = "Lorem ipsum".ValueOrNull<Guid>() // result -> Guid.Empty
var f = "5cc1c2ad-f6ba-4412-96c5-3bb50e87cff1".ValueOrNull<Guid>() // result -> ok
```